# How can I change polymer element template by passing param attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer, web-component

I'm creating a slider web component from scratch to learn.

I want the button to hide when the attribute `controlVisible` is `false` and show when it's `true`, but my selector `$('#botaoVoltar')` doesn't get anything.

What am I missing?

*index.html:*

```
<body>
    <slider-js controlVisible='false' ></slider-js>
</body>
```

*polymer.html:*

```
<polymer-element name="slider-js">
    <template>
        <center>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="Buttons">
                    <button name="voltar" id="botaoVoltar"><<</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </center>
    </template>
</polymer-element>

<script>
    Polymer('slider-js', {
        controlVisible: false,

        ready: function () {
            if (this.controlVisible === false) {
                $('#botaoVoltar').hide();
            } else {
                $('#botaoVoltar').show();
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

The attribute is working fine. If I `console.log` it, I can see if it is `true` or `false`, but the template still renders with the button.

Comment: tbh, I'd start by [upgrading to Polymer 1+](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery can't get at Polymer's local DOM, so you'd have to use Polymer's own [DOM API](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#dom-api). Actually, Polymer's [automatic node finding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#node-finding) provides quick access to nodes that have IDs with `this.$`. For instance, you could access the `botaoVoltar` button in your example with `this.$.botaoVoltar`.

It looks like you're using old Polymer (pre 1.0). You should switch to the latest version of Polymer (1.5.0). Here's your code upgraded to the newest Polymer version:

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.5.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <span>With control-visible:</span>
  <x-slider control-visible></x-slider>

  <span>Without control-visible:</span>
  <x-slider></x-slider>

  <!-- Normally, you would define this element in its own file. -->
  <dom-module id="x-slider">
    <template>
      <div id="container">
        <div id="Buttons">
          <button id="botaoVoltar">&lt;&lt;</button>
          <button>&gt;&gt;</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        Polymer({
          is: 'x-slider',

          properties : {
            controlVisible: {
              type: Boolean,
              value: false
            }
          },

          ready: function() {
            this.$.botaoVoltar.hidden = !this.controlVisible;
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

<sup>[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/jrVGje?editors=1000)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @tony19, it's hard to find good study material in portuguese, i think i was mixing different versions tutorials... 

it worked in the same file, but it needs to be in separated files to become a reusable component, and i'm not managing to make it work... my guess is about the dependencies.

How should I structure the dependencies, and call my polymer in index.html?

Comment: @lucasumberto No problem :-) Regarding the dependencies issue, it's difficult for me to tell without seeing your project. I recommend posting a new question so that you can reach a broader audience, who might be able to help you better than I can. I'd be happy to help you as well. Can you include a link to your code repo (or at least a clear description to reproduce your problem)?

Comment: thaks again.... 
its a mess, it's my first time using bower as well, i think there are a lot of unnecessary files there... feel free to contact me, thanks for your help github.com/lucasumberto/slider im having this error: Uncaught Element name could not be inferred. (19:33:28:295 | error, javascript)
  at public_html/bower_components/polymer/polymer.js:10271

Comment: @lucasumberto Seems like a third question :) I recommend creating a new post for it to get some attention.